# How do you securely have a non-admin run a powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, service, credentials, windows-server-2016

I have an issue with a remote site whose printer occasionally errors out. The current solution is to restart the print spooler on the server.

I am trying to create a simple powershell script that allows a non-admin user to restart the Spooler service without being able to see the admin credentials or edit the script.

We are replacing the server in a couple of months, so the configuration will be fixable then. We just need a temporary workaround so the user doesn't need to email me every couple of days when the spooler requires resetting.

Ideas?

Comment: I am looking for the field in the XML to edit. What gets edited in the XML to allow nonadmins to run the task?

Comment: The right to run the task is driven by the Security tab the task XML file's Properties window in Explorer. Right click, "Properties", "Security".

Answer (score 1):

Create a scheduled task with the admin credentials cached. Under Actions, have the task run the privileged Powershell script: `powershell c:\Path\MyScript.ps1`. Assign no schedule (i. e. delete all triggers). Change the permissions on the task's XML file under `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` to allow read/execute by nonadmins. Create a user facing CMD script (or a shortcut, even) that would run the task: `schtasks /Run /TN:MyTaskName /S:Server`.

There are other ways to isolate the credentials, but this seems to be the easiest.

Comment: Sounds solid! I'll give it a shot. I'm not familiar with XML, but I'll see if I can figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: You won't need to edit the XML. The Windows Task Scheduler application is where you create/edit the task, but in order to grant rights, you'd have to find the task's XML file in Explorer and work some security magic.

Comment: Important, make sure to change the NTFS permissions on `c:\Path\MyScript.ps1` to deny any non-admin user to edit it. Otherwise anybody could change the script's content and make themselves an administration.

Comment: I am trying to edit that xml in notepad. I just don't know what field to change. Sorry guys, I'm pretty new at this. 
Peter, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Don't! Click Start in Windows, type "task", open the app called "Task Scheduler". It will let you create scheduled tasks. Menu, Action, Create task. Will you figure it out from there?